# Does "MeanMarker" (BoxWhiskerChart) exclude outliers?

Tags: plotting, charts

When you use the `"MeanMarker"` function within `BoxWhiskerChart`, does the mean shown on the box plot exclude the near and/or far outliers identified from the plot?

If not, is there a (relatively simple) way to have the mean marker shown on the plot exclude outliers?

Answer (score 4):

In answer to the first question, no, the mean does not exclude outliers:

```
SeedRandom[1]
r = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]^2;

fence = Quantile[r, 0.95]
mean1 = Mean[r]
mean2 = Mean @ DeleteCases[r, x_ /; x > fence]
```

> ```
> 3.33858
>
> 1.01835
>
> 0.770329
> ```

```
BoxWhiskerChart[r, {{"Outliers"}, {"MeanMarker"}}, 
 GridLines -> {{}, {fence, mean1, mean2}}]
```

[image]

Regarding the second question one could calculate these as I did for `mean2` above and plot them with [`Epilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html) but there may be a simpler way.  I'll see what I can find.

Comment: Have you looked at `TrimmedMean[]`, by any chance?

Comment: @J.M. Thanks for the hint!  Despite that being around since version 6 I don't think I have ever used it.

Answer (score 3):

```
ClearAll[trimmedMeansF]
trimmedMeansF[dir_: Directive[Thick, Opacity[1, Red]]] := BoxWhiskerChart[
   ConstantArray[#, 2] & /@ TrimmedMean[Transpose@#, {0, .05}],
  {{"Fences", None}, {"Whiskers", Opacity[0]}, {"MedianMarker", 
      Opacity[0]}, {"MeanMarker", .8, dir}}] &;
```

Example:

```
SeedRandom[1]
r = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 100]^2;
rr = {r, 1 + r, 2 + r};

Legended[Show[BoxWhiskerChart[rr,{{"Outliers"}, {"MeanMarker", Directive[Thick, Yellow]}}, 
                  ChartStyle -> 1, GridLines -> {None, Mean@Transpose@rr}], 
              trimmedMeansF[Directive[Thick, Cyan]]@rr], 
 LineLegend[Directive[Thick, #] & /@ {Yellow, Cyan}, {"means", "trimmed means"}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Alternatively, post-process to modify the position of the mean markers:

```
means1 = Mean@Transpose@rr;
means2 = TrimmedMean[Transpose@rr, {0, .05}];
bwc = BoxWhiskerChart[rr, {{"Outliers"}, {"MeanMarker", Directive[Thick, Yellow]}}, 
   GridLines -> {None, means1}, PlotLabel -> TableForm[{means1, means2}, 
     TableHeadings -> {{"means", "trimmedmeans"}, {"data1", "data2", "data3"}}], 
   ChartStyle -> 1, ImageSize -> 400];

Row[{bwc, bwc /. With[{sel = Select[Cases[bwc, _LineBox, Infinity], 
       Not[FreeQ[#, Alternatives @@ means1]] &]}, 
    Thread[sel -> ( sel /. Thread[means1 -> means2])]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]